# AWS Openshift not able to connect to webconsole

Tags: openshift

I am unable to open AWS Openshift  webconsole...I am able to execute oc cli commands...

```
oc cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://api.testopenshift.test.co.uk:6443

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

When I try the console, I get "Secure Connection failure PR_CONNECTION_RESET_ERROR"

Comment: Although I can't go through the login form: looks like it works. I guess that error is somewhat random? Have you checked the authentication cluster operator status? Its related Pods logs? Sidenote: it's usually not recommended to share Kubernetes API endpoint addresses.

Comment: thanks much..I removed the api endpoints...I will check the logs of operator..yeah its trying to load and then this error appears

Answer (score 0):

Finally it turned out to be vpn issue :) Once I disabled my company's vpn, I was able to access web console..